# Bug em um código em C

Tags: c, debug

Eu sei, esse código é bem simples e ta meio feio tbm, sou iniciante e estou tentando facilitar essa função, alguém pode me dizer qual o erro?

Imagem do bug:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char tempo[5],a[25];
int op;

printf("EAE MEN\n\n1.Apagar o bixin\n2.Desligar e ligar dnv\n3.Tirar uma sonequinha\n");
scanf("%d",&op);

switch(op){
case 1:
a=="shutdown -s -t ";
printf("Desliga em qts segundos msm?\n");
scanf(" %s",tempo);
strcat(a,tempo);
break;
case 2:
a=="shutdown -r -t ";
printf("Reinicia em qts segundos msm?\n");
scanf(" %s",tempo);
strcat(a,tempo);
break;
case 3:
a=="shutdown -h -t ";
printf("Sonequinha em qts segundos msm?\n");
scanf(" %s",tempo);
strcat(a,tempo);
break;
default:
printf("Numero Invalido, bro, sabe ler n eh?\n");
return 0;
}
system(a);

return 0;
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Seria bom [edit] e colocar o código na pergunta. Referências externas só devem ser usadas como complemento (e isso é melhor para quem for te ajudar já ver o problema todo num lugar só). Além disso, é melhor postar o erro como texto, e não como imagem.

Comment: Ao invés de fotos do erro você pode copiar o erro e colar diretamente aqui, fora que isso não é um BUG e sim um erro seu, BUG seria se fosse falha no compilador C que você usa, mas o caso ae é um erro seu. **Leia:** [Postar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3635)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando o operador relacional `==`em vez do operador de atribuição `=`, em todas as declarações em que  `a`, string de caracteres, é operador da esquerda.

A string `a` trata-se de um array do tipo `char`. Em C, você não pode fazer um declaração de atribuição para este tipo de dado. Você precisa usar a função `strcpy(arrayDeDestino, arrayFonte)`.

Comment: errei ali na hora de mandar o código, eu tava colocando com = msm (como pode ver no erro no cmd), coloquei == só pra testar msm sabendo q tava errado e mandei o errado, ce sabe me dizer qual o erro msm com um =

Comment: Eu editei a resposta para ficar mais amplo.